# Url.OriginalString vs Url.AbsoluteUri

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString and HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri?

I need to get the URL in the page load, but confused about the both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the url, you could get the same result. It depends how exact you want it to be, if you want all fragments, and how you want to use it.

The following is for `Uri` but I think it applies to `Url` too (a url is a uri, essentially).

**AbsoluteUri**

> The AbsoluteUri property includes the entire URI stored in the Uri instance, including all fragments and query strings.

This

```
Uri baseUri= new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri,"catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");
Console.WriteLine(myUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

will return

```
http://www.contoso.com/catalog/shownew.htm?date=today
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri(v=vs.110).aspx

---

**Uri.OriginalString**

> Gets the original URI string that was passed to the Uri constructor.

The following example creates a new Uri instance from a string. It illustrates the difference between the value returned from OriginalString, which returns the string that was passed to the constructor, and from a call to ToString, which returns the canonical form of the string.

```
// Create a new Uri from a string address.
Uri uriAddress = new Uri("HTTP://www.ConToso.com:80//thick%20and%20thin.htm");

// Write the new Uri to the console and note the difference in the two values.
// ToString() gives the canonical version.  OriginalString gives the orginal 
// string that was passed to the constructor.

// The following outputs "http://www.contoso.com/thick and thin.htm".
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress.ToString()); 

// The following outputs "HTTP://www.ConToso.com:80//thick%20and%20thin.htm".
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress.OriginalString);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Uri properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification